# Ruby markdown interpreter with syntax similar to GitHub Flavored Markdown?

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, pygments, github-flavored-markdown

I run a blog using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), and thought I'd settle with [Redcarpet](http://rubygems.org/gems/redcarpet) markdown interpreter as it's [developed and used by GitHub](https://github.com/blog/832-rolling-out-the-redcarpet).

Well, I just happened to come across a bug, went to checkout the issues, and [found this](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/issues/212).

> Maintainer says, *"As you probably have noticed (har har har har) I don't have time to maintain Redcarpet anymore. It's not a priority for me (I find Markdown thoroughly boring) and **it's not a priority for GitHub, because we no longer use it in production.**"*

So...

1. Is there a good Ruby markdown interpreter (i.e. actively developed, with sane syntax) that I can use with Jekyll (& pygments)?
2. Even better, a markdown interpreter with syntax similar to (or at least close to) GitHub Flavored Markdown?

Answer (score 10):

https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet Redcarpet is very actively developed and was updated about 8 hours ago (at the time of this writing.)

For "flavoring" your Markdown: https://rubygems.org/gems/github-markdown

To convert Markdown to HTML:

```
GitHub::Markdown.render_gfm("# Header")
```

To render within Rails:

```
GitHub::Markdown.render_gfm("# Header").html_safe
```

Want syntax highlighting?
https://github.com/simplabs/highlight
https://alphahydrae.com/2013/01/markdown-views-in-rails/

Cheers!

Comment: Do you know what the difference between [Redcarpet](https://rubygems.org/gems/redcarpet) and [Github-markdown](https://rubygems.org/gems/github-markdown) is? Redcarpet seems more popular, but thats all.

Comment: Github added lots of features. Redcarpet is little behind.